# Accessing arbitrary rows in Julia matrix

Tags: matrix, types, julia, slice, argument-error

I have the following code, where given `i` I want to find the `i`th row of a matrix. My code is the following:

```
function f(mat,i)
     println(mat[:i,:])
end
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid index: :i of type Symbol
```

I have tried printing the type of `i` using `typeof` and it says it is `Int64`. Further, if I attempt to just find the first row then `mat[:1,:]` does the job so I don't think the problem is with the slicing syntax.

Comment: It is with the slicing syntax I believe

Comment: But why does the syntax work stand alone?

Comment: Because for Julia parser `:1` is the same as just `1`. In Julia you do not need to slice to get the row of the matrix - just passing a row number is enough.

Comment: The answer below goes into detail, but the short answer is to just write `mat[i, :]`. The colon in front of `i` makes it into a symbol, which is not the same as the value of the variable `i`. Why did you put the colon there, btw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get e.g. the first row of a matrix like this:

```
julia> x = rand(4, 5)
4×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.995364  0.00204836  0.0821081  0.732777   0.705893
 0.4392    0.151428    0.0978743  0.184995   0.867329
 0.863659  0.367339    0.252248   0.235425   0.0343476
 0.756938  0.119276    0.857559   0.0982663  0.938148

julia> x[1, :]
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.9953642825497493
 0.0020483620556226434
 0.0821081267390984
 0.7327765477421397
 0.7058932509878071

julia> x[1:1, :]
1×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.995364  0.00204836  0.0821081  0.732777  0.705893
```

Note that normally you just pass a row number (in my case `1`) to signal the row you want to fetch. In this case as a result you get a `Vector`.

However, you can use slicing `1:1` which gets a 1-element range of rows. In this case the result is a `Matrix` having one row.

---

Now the issue of `:1`. See below:

```
julia> :1
1

julia> typeof(:1)
Int64

julia> :1 == 1
true

julia> :x
:x

julia> typeof(:x)
Symbol
```

As you can see `:1` is just the same as `1`. However, e.g. `:x` is a special type called `Symbol`. Its most common use is to represent field names in structs. Since field names cannot start with a number (variable names in Julia, as also in other programming languages) have to start with something else, e.g. a letter `x` as in my example, there is no ambiguity here. Putting `:` in front of a number is a no-op, while putting it in front of a valid variable identifier creates a `Symbol`. See the help for `Symbol` in the Julia REPL for more examples.

---

In Julia ranges **always** require passing start and end i.e. `a:b` is a range starting from `a` and ending with `b` inclusive, examples:

```
julia> 1:1
1:1

julia> collect(1:1)
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 1

julia> 2:4
2:4

julia> collect(2:4)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 4
```

Comment: Very well written, this should be in the upcoming manning book!

Comment: If you have arrays which allow non-standard indexes (e.g., using `OffsetArrays`), you can also write this generically with `x[begin, :]` or `x[begin:begin, :]`.